# SQL Flatten inheritance

Tags: mysql, sql, inheritance, tree, sql-view

I have this `groups` table in MySQL

| id | name | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | *null* |
| 2 | B | *null* |
| 3 | C | *null* |
| 4 | A-A | 1 |
| 5 | A-B | 1 |
| 6 | A-A-A | 4 |
| 7 | A-B-A | 5 |
| 8 | A-B-A-A | 7 |
| 9 | B-A | 2 |

I want to create a MySQL view with every pair of a child and any of its parents. Like this

| child_id | parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 5 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 7 |
| 8 | 5 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 2 |

I have tried using recursive like the following but this only creates pairs for the first level of parents.

```
CREATE VIEW groups_inheritance AS
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (SELECT id AS child_id, parent_id
                       FROM groups
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT g.id AS child_id, g.parent_id
                       FROM groups g
                                INNER JOIN cte ON g.id = cte.parent_id)
SELECT *
FROM cte
```

I also found this in another thread and as far as I understand it creates pairs for up to the second level.

```
WITH RECURSIVE generation AS (
    SELECT id,
         parent_id,
         0 AS generation_number
    FROM groups
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL

UNION ALL

    SELECT g.id,
         g.parent_id,
         generation_number+1 AS generation_number
    FROM groups g
    inner JOIN generation gen
      ON gen.id = g.parent_id

)
SELECT *
FROM generation gen
 JOIN groups parent
 ON gen.parent_id = parent.id;
```

The application does not limit the user to the level of nesting, so I am looking for a solution covering any level of nesting. Otherwise I If that is a problem I think the max level it could be reached is 6.
Do you have any suggestions on how to create that MySQL view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS (
    SELECT id, parent_id, CAST(id AS CHAR(65535)) path
    FROM `groups`
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `groups`.id, cte.id, CONCAT_WS(',', cte.path, `groups`.id)
    FROM cte
    JOIN `groups` ON cte.id = `groups`.parent_id
)
SELECT t1.id child_id, t2.id parent_id
FROM cte t1
JOIN cte t2 ON LOCATE(t2.path, t1.path) AND t1.id <> t2.id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb8a506b120c5ff0fe028c92cf7f5b0e

Of course, this query does not provide "a solution covering any level of nesting" which is defined by the maximal length defined for `path` column of CTE (from the other side some reasonable limit must exist - define and use it).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @Akina. However on ids with multiple digits this does not work completely correct. It includes other group ids with digits in the same order, for example the parent `t2.path` `1` will match the child  t1.path `126,128,228,229`

Comment: I fixed the error by wrapping the paths like this `CONCAT('"',id,'"')` and it works perfect. Again Thank You